# Training DQN Agent slows down and then at around 50 episodes

Tags: reinforcement-learning, dqn

I am training a DQN Agent at around 50 episodes the fit in the replay function starts slowing down and starts freezing the PC. After a while PyCharm just crashes.

This is the relevant part of the agent
The input is just an array with 12 different floats

```
        model = Sequential()
        model.add(Dense(64, input_dim=self.state_size, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
        model.add(Dense(self.action_size, activation='linear'))
        model.compile(loss=keras.losses.Huber(), optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
        return model

    def act(self, state):
        if np.random.random() > self.epsilon:
            actions = self.model.predict(state)
            return np.argmax(actions[0])
        else:
            return np.random.randint(0, self.action_size)

    def remember(self, state, action, reward, next_state, done):
        self.memory.append((state, action, reward, next_state, done))

    def replay(self, batch_size):
        minibatch = random.sample(self.memory, batch_size)
        for state, action, reward, next_state, done in minibatch:
            target = reward
            if not done:
                try:
                    target = (reward + self.gamma *
                              np.amax(self.model.predict(next_state)[0]))
                except:
                    print(next_state, next_state.shape, type(next_state))
            target_f = self.model.predict(state)
            target_f[0][action] = target
            self.model.fit(state, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
```

Here is my training loop

```
def train_dqn(agent, env: gym.Env, episodes: int, batch_size: int, episode_length: int):

    ep_rewards = []
    aggr_ep_rewards = {'ep': [], 'avg': [], 'max': [], 'min': []}
    STATS_EVERY = 5

    START_EPSILON_DECAYING = 1
    END_EPSILON_DECAYING = episodes // 2
    epsilon_decay_value = agent.epsilon / (END_EPSILON_DECAYING - START_EPSILON_DECAYING)

    for episode in range(episodes):
        total_reward = 0
        # reset state in the beginning of each game
        state = env.reset()
        state = encode_state(state)
        # Loop over time steps until the episode is done or the time limit is reached
        for i in range(episode_length):
            action = agent.act(state)
            decoded_action = decode_action(action, state, env.action_space)
            next_state, reward, done, _, _ = env.step(decoded_action)
            encoded_next_state = encode_state(next_state)
            agent.remember(state, action, reward, encoded_next_state, done)
            state = encoded_next_state
            total_reward += reward
            if (episode * 29) % 58 == 0:
                if len(agent.memory) > batch_size:
                    agent.replay(batch_size)

        ep_rewards.append(total_reward)

        if not episode % STATS_EVERY:
            average_reward = sum(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]) / STATS_EVERY
            aggr_ep_rewards['ep'].append(episode)
            aggr_ep_rewards['avg'].append(average_reward)
            aggr_ep_rewards['max'].append(max(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            aggr_ep_rewards['min'].append(min(ep_rewards[-STATS_EVERY:]))
            print(
                f'Episode: {episode:>5d}, average reward: {average_reward:>4.1f}, current epsilon: {agent.epsilon:>1.2f}')

        if END_EPSILON_DECAYING >= episode >= START_EPSILON_DECAYING:
            if agent.epsilon - epsilon_decay_value >= 0:
                agent.epsilon -= epsilon_decay_value

        print("episode: {}/{}, score: {}, e: {:.2}"
              .format(episode, episodes, total_reward, agent.epsilon))

        if episode % 10 == 0:
            agent.save(f"models/model_{episode}.h5")

    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['avg'], label="average rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['max'], label="max rewards")
    plt.plot(aggr_ep_rewards['ep'], aggr_ep_rewards['min'], label="min rewards")
    plt.legend(loc=4)
    plt.show()
    agent.save(f"model_{episodes}.h5")
    return agent
```

Batch size is 32 and memory is a deque with size 500
I have tried changing batch size.
I have reinstalled CUDA and removed everything related to CUDA and just training on CPU.
I have tried changing the neural net size to smaller and larger.
Changing the frequency of the replay function just makes it crash earlier or later in the training process.
What could cause this? Is this something in my code or is this an issue with my pc or operating system?

Comment: Try `model.train_on_batch` instead of `model.fit` within the replay fn. Otherwise just profile your code; also I think this question best suits stackoverflow..

Comment: I will try that. If it doesn't work I will post it on stackoverflow. Thanks!